# How to find the length and width of a random shaped object which was selected using Contours approach OpenCV in C++ / CLI

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, contour

Well I am selecting different randomly shaped objects using find contours OpenCV function in C++/CLI application.

I want to find the maximum length of every contour in the image. and width of the contour with the different of 40 to 50 pixels every time. Can you please help me.

```
findContours(K, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); for(idx=0; idx<contours.size(); idx++)
{
    double cArea = contourArea(contours[idx]);

    // get only contours with area above specific threshold
    if (cArea > min_area && cArea < 40000)// && !k )
    {
        if (cArea > largest_area) {
            largest_area = cArea; 

            largest_contour_index = idx;

           // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
            bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        }

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j<contours[idx].size(); j++)      
        {
            circle(dst, Point(contours[idx][j].x, contours[idx][j].y), 3, Scalar(255, 255,0), FILLED, LINE_AA);

        }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming findContours(..,contours,.....) is what you are using, with the result contours going into

```
   std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
```

You have 4 different options

1. Fit an unrotated rectangle to each contour

   ```
    //Assuming right version of C++
    for(const auto& it: contours){
    Rect boundingRect = boundingRect(it);
    // boundRect.height, boundingRect.width will give you what you 
     //need
     }
   ```
2. Fit an rotated rectangle to each contour

   ```
    //Assuming C++ 11
    for(const auto& it: contours){
    RotatedRect rotRect = minAreaRect(it);
    // rotRect.size.height, rotRect.size.width will give you what you 
     //need
     }
   ```
3. Fit an enclosing circle to each contour

   ```
    //Assuming C++ 11
    for(const auto& it: contours){
    Point2f center;
    float radius;
    minEnclosingCircle(it, center, radius);
    }
   ```
4. Fit an ellipse to each contour

   ```
    //Assuming C++ 11
    for(const auto& it: contours){
    // note need atleast 5 points to fit an ellipse
    if(it.size()>5){
    RotatedRect boundingEllipse = minBoundingEllipse(it);
    }
    // boundingEllipse.size.height, boundingEllipse.size.width will 
    //give you what you need - in this case the major and minor axis
    }
   ```

4 is the most accurate usually. 2 and 4 also give you more information if needed (center, angle)

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Width and length we are finding with this approach is only calculated from the area of contour or also contains the area of eclipse which is not the part of contour. And contour shape is completely random and different width on different angles. so which area it is going to select for the width and length. Largest one or? And I want to get the unit of length and width also like millimeter or in inches.

Comment: I'm using following approach you shared with me:  for (const auto& it : contours) {
  // note need atleast 5 points to fit an ellipse

  if (it.size() > 5) {
   //RotatedRect boundingEllipse = minBoundingEllipse(it);

   RotatedRect boundingEllipse = fitEllipse(it);

   float crack_height = boundingEllipse.size.height;
   float crack_width = boundingEllipse.size.width;
   //float crack_area = boundingEllipse.size.area;

   ellipse(tempimage, boundingEllipse, (0, 0, 255), 2);
  }
 }

Comment: and it gives me error on : float crack_area = boundingEllipse.size.area;

Comment: @DavidHorn 
I am pretty sure there isnt an attribute area for the attribute size.
In case you need area of the ellipse, you would calculate that yourself as 
      pi*(boundingEllipse.size.width)*(boundingEllipse.size.height)

Or you can directly find the area of the contours with
      contourArea(it)

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how to find the sub contours or regions inside one contour. I want to divide every contour in different subcontractors or regions and then want to calculate the width of every sub contour or region. Then I want to categories on the basis of width of every region. Thanks again.

Comment: you use CV_RETR_LIST which retrieves all of the contours without establishing any hierarchical relationships. you can use other flags to specify how you want the contours retrieved
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

Also be sure to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Dear thanks for your quick response. Well CV_RETR_LIST gives us all the contours in an image. But I want to divide every contour in different regions (for example 10 equal regions) and then wants to calculate the width of all the regions which should not include the pixels outside that particular contour. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And I want to store all the inside points of every contour in a separate array.